# Rails 4 - jQuery not loading after navigating to another page

Tags: jquery, html, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript file that runs on `$(document).ready(function() {});` and this works fine until I navigate to another page on the website, and then return to the original page.  Once I return, the jQuery stops functioning.

I initially fixed this by including a `<%= javascript_include_tag "xyz" %>`in the body of the specific page, but this resulted in the js file loading twice causing events to fire twice when they occurred (often offsetting one another).

Any thoughts on how to fix this bug without loading the js file twice? For the record, I have tried other events such as `load` `pageinit`, etc.

### application.js

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//= require_tree .
//= require bootstrap-sprockets
//= require owl.carousel
//= require moment
//= require bootstrap-datetimepicker
//= require jquery-ui
//= require turbolinks
```

### testing.js

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".glyphicon-remove").on("click", function(e) {
        prevAngle = angle;
        angle +=45;

        $(this).animateRotate(angle, prevAngle, 1000);
        e.preventDefault();

        $('.instructions').find('h1').toggleClass('smallfont', 1000);
        $(this).parent().toggleClass("btn-sm");

        if ( $(".instructions").hasClass("isDown") ) {
            $('.instructions').animate({
                top: '30%',
                width: '50%',
                left: '25%'
            }, 1000);
        } else {
            $('.instructions').animate({
                top: '94%',
                width: '100%',
                left: '0',
            }, 1000);
        }

        $(".instructions").toggleClass("isDown");
        $('.instructions').toggleClass('instructions-small');
        $('.instructions').toggleClass('instructions-min');
    });
});
```

### application.html.erb

```
<head>
  <title><%= yield(:title) %> | Boston EDM Show Rewards</title>
  <%= favicon_link_tag 'favicon.ico' %>
  <%= stylesheet_link_tag    "application", media: "all", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= javascript_include_tag "application", "data-turbolinks-track" => true %>
  <%= csrf_meta_tags %>
</head>
```

Comment: Update your question with relevant code, It will help to give idea's :) Also, when you return to original page, is it full page refresh ? did you also tried by cleaning browser cache ?

Comment: I normally would have, but I'm not sure what code would be useful?  the Javascript?  The HTML?  I feel like this is a problem outside of the way the code was written

Comment: Javascript.. Do you see any errors in browser console ?

Comment: It is showing an error in the turbolinks js file

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like a Turbolinks issue.  Either remove Turbolinks, or add the [jquery-turbolinks gem](https://github.com/kossnocorp/jquery.turbolinks).  Don't forget to add `jquery.turbolinks` to your application.js file.

```
//= require jquery
//= require jquery.turbolinks
//= require jquery_ujs
//
// ... your other scripts here ...
//
//= require turbolinks
```

Comment: I tried that, maybe one of the others is out of order as well?  I included the `application.js` file above